# what does this ruby error with <<~ and &. mean?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

reviving and old codebase. installed it in new docker env.  when i start the app, i get this error.  i'm not a ruby guy, dunno what this <<~ nor &. means.   i've already bundle installed from the Gemfile.   this app is still running in another environment but I don't have shell access to that environment currently.

```
WARNING: If you plan to load any of ActiveSupport's core extensions to Hash, be
sure to do so *before* loading Sinatra::Application or Sinatra::Base. If not,
you may disregard this warning.

Set SINATRA_ACTIVESUPPORT_WARNING=false in the environment to hide this warning.
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.0.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/base.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected <<
        <<~SQL
          ^
/usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.0.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/base.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected '.'
...veRecord::Base.configurations&.configs_for(name: db)&.config...
...                               ^
/usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.0.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/base.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected '.'
...ations&.configs_for(name: db)&.configuration_hash
...                               ^
/usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.0.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/transaction.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.0.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/transaction.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.0.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record.rb:3:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-active_record-2.0.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-2.0.1/lib/database_cleaner.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/config/environments/shared.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/app/tasks/db.rake:2:in `require_relative'
/app/tasks/db.rake:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => dl:start:all => dl:start:job_queue => dl:start:queue => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: The first is a "squiggly heredoc" ("<<~"), the second is a safe navigation operator ("&.") both are red herrings in this case. The issue is that your ruby version is pre 2.3.0

Comment: i did try to build it on ruby:latest and got these errors.  sounds like some type definition missing that's used by the json gem

generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
generator.c:861:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this function);
did you mean ‘mFixnum’?
     } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                         ^~~~~~~~~~
                         mFixnum
generator.c:861:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
each function it appears in
generator.c:863:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 1):

As engineersmnky already pointed out in the comment, both operators – the squiggly heredocs (`<<~`) and the safe navigation operator (`&.`) – were introduced in Ruby version 2.3. This means your application needs at least Ruby 2.3 and does not support older versions.

At the same time, when updating your Ruby environment to the latest version, your application complains about `Fixnum` and `Bignum` missing. Both classes were deprecated in Ruby 2.4 and removed shortly after. That means your application doesn't support Ruby 2.4 or above.

That said: It looks like your application is only able to run against Ruby 2.3. I suggest installing the latest Ruby 2.3 version which is `2.3.8` and try again.

Please note that even the 2.3.8 version is already more than two and a half years old and that Ruby 2.3 reached end-of-life, is unmaintained, and will not get any bug fixes or security updates anymore. Even if your application worked with Ruby 2.3.8, I highly recommend updating it to Ruby 2.7.3 or – even better Ruby 3.0.1